# how to add event handler for search button on the search key pad in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, event-handling

how to add event handler for the search button on the search key pad in obj c for an iphone app, thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `UISearchBar`, you should assign it a delegate object. That delegate should conform to `UISearchBarDelegate` [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate), and then you can implement:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```